# How to achieve the name of QListWidgetitem?

Tags: python, list, user-interface, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I'm working with my pyqt5 project and I reach a problem. I made a QlistWidget and I don't know how to achieve the name of field. When I try to do that I saw that the item is an object. So how to achieve the name of this object:

```
class Chooseaticket(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,item):
        super(Chooseaticket,self).__init__()
        loadUi("airrport3.ui",self)
        self.setup_ticket_list(item)
    def setup_ticket_list(self,item):
        self.ticketlist.addItems(["Ekonomiczny", "Biznes", "Premium"])
        lotName = item.lot
        # bramkaname = itemm.idlotu
        data = lotName.split(".")
        number = data[0]
        lot = read_from_csv("loty.txt")
        get_lot = lot.get_loty_by_numer_lotu(number)
        cenaek = get_lot.get_cenaek()
        cenabiz = get_lot.get_cenabiz()
        cenapr = get_lot.get_cenapr()
        self.price_of_ek.setText(f'Cena za bilet w klasie ekonomicznej:{cenaek}')
        self.price_of_biz.setText(f'Cena za bilet w klasie biznesowej :{cenabiz}')
        self.price_of_pr.setText(f'Cena za bilet w klasie premium:{cenapr}')
        bilet_class = self.ticketlist.itemClicked
        if bilet_class == "Ekonomiczny":
            price = cenaek
        if bilet_class == "Biznes":
            price = cenabiz
        if bilet_class == "Premium":
            price = cenapr
        ticket = Ticket(bilet_class, price)
        self.ticketlist.itemClicked.connect(self.gotonewwindow)
```

Comment: "When I try to do that", but where are you trying that? Show us the code of `gotonewwindow`.

Comment: `name = item.text()` (See: [QListWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidgetitem.html#text)).